# OpenAI_API.Model.DavinciText giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Has anyone tried integrating ChatGPT Completions into C# Application before?

I am trying to integrate it by implementing:

```
completionRequest.Model = OpenAI_API.Model.DavinciText;
```

The issue that I am having is that I am getting a Compiler Error CS0234 for "OpenAI_API.Model.DavinciText" saying:

The type or namespace name 'Model' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenAI_API' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I tried implementing an assembly reference but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please check the following]

Hi here is the solution. you just need to provide the string and issue will be fixed.

completionRequest.Model = "gpt-3.5-turbo";